# Почему функция определения высоты iframe каждый раз определяет разные значения?

Tags: javascript, html

Приведенная ниже функция выполняется по атрибуту onload у iframe, для того чтобы растягивать iframe на высоту, соответствующую его содержимому и избавлять от полоски прокрутки.

Код функции:

`function resizeIframe(iframe) { let elem = document.getElementById('myFrame'); let size=elem.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight; elem.style.height = size + "px"; }`

Во время каждой загрузки страницы, содержащей iframe, высота iframe почему то устанавливается разная. Содержимое страницы, загружаемой в iframe, неизменно, как и ширина окна браузера. Почему всегда задается разный height у iframe и как это побороть?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, ты не единственный, кто выполняет код в onload. Соответственно, если какие-то данные ещё не пришли и не отрисовались, ты получаешь одну высоту, а если отрисовались, то другую.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо `elem.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` брать `elem.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight`

```
function resizeIframe(iframe) { 
  let elem = document.getElementById('myFrame'); 
  let size=elem.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight; 
  elem.style.height = size + "px"; 
}
```

Comment: Это не помогло.

Comment: Вероятнее всего, проблема не в этом участке. Покажите содержимое обеих разметок

Comment: Заметил что к iframe добавляется класс class="lazyloaded". Сайт на WordPress и там используется плагин Hummingbird для ускорения загрузки. На сколько понимаю, класс lazyloaded добавляет этот плагин и каждый раз значение высоты в этом классе почему то отличается. Еще этот Hummingbird ломал кнопки отправки форм. Если в хроме в просмотре кода (ctrl+shift+i) удаляю class="lazyloaded" то высота фрейма становится той которая нужна. Вот теперь думаю, отказаться от Hummingbird или какой то JS скрипт использовать, который будет убирать class="lazyloaded" у iframe.

Comment: Лучше отказаться от плагина, чем костылировать скрипты по удалению классов или id'шников.